# How do I separate a string that contains brand, part-number and description in separate columns in Rstudio?

Tags: r, string

I want to separate from a string: information such as brand (Toyota), part-number(87910-60142), and description of the part-number  (ESPEJO RET.EXT.RH MA) into separate columns in Rstudio

This is a data set of automotive part-numbers that were imported.

```
ESPEJO RET.EXT.RH MA 87910-60142 TOYOTA
```

Comment: What did you try to do to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Hi Pavlo, this data is in a column

Comment: Does your data have the same structure (i.e., description, part-number, and then brand)? Can you post more data samples?

Comment: Hi Teekea, can I send you the file so you can check it out?

Comment: @Edwin I see the data but I haven't see any your attempt to achieve expected result